# Multi-Key Custom Sorting in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

**Problem Statement:**

I want to sort an `std::vector` of a structure using my custom sorting criteria.

The structure is:

```
struct Node
{
   int x;
   int y;
   float value;
};
```

The vector is:

```
std::vector<Node> vec;
```

My custom sorting criteria is that the vector should first be sorted by `y` and then by `x` (just like in Microsoft Excel).

### Example:

**Input:**

```
x y

5 6
2 4
1 1
1 0
8 10
4 7
7 1
5 4
6 1
1 4
3 10
7 2
```

**Output:**

```
x y

1 0
1 1
6 1
7 1
7 2
1 4
2 4
5 4
5 6
4 7
3 10
8 10
```

Can the above mentioned sorting be achieved through any of the C++ Standard Library sorting functions? If not, is there any other library which I can use?

Comment: yes, you can use `std::sort` with a custom functor. See example here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) using a comparison function.

```
bool comparison(const Node& node1, const Node& node2)
{
    if (node1.y < node2.y) return true;
    if (node1.y == node2.y) return node1.x < node2.x;

    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comparison);
}
```

Comment: I would add remarks that you can use any functor (and with C++11 lambda functions)

Comment: wow, thankyou so much. I tried with a comparator function but did not think of this logic for comparison. :)

Answer (score 5):

In general, implementing comparison operators (and functions) for multiple fields is more clearly expressed in terms of [tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) when **lexicographical ordering** is required.

```
static bool compare(Node const& l, Node const& r) {
    // Note the alignment so that both expressions only differ in their `l` and `r` ?
    return std::tie(l.y, l.x)
         < std::tie(r.y, r.x);
}
```

However, even that leaves some duplication and route for inconsistency. The following helper sees to that:

```
static std::tuple<int&,int&> tuplize(Node const& n) { return std::tie(n.y, n.x); }
```

which can then be applied simply:

```
static bool compare(Node const& l, Node const& r) {
    return tuplize(l) < tuplize(r);
}
```

Taaadaaam :)

Answer (score 3):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function:

```
std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [](const Node& a, const Node& b) {
    return a.y < b.y || (a.y == b.y && a.x < b.x);
});
```

This way you can keep your code rather short.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/O4oZBZ)

Answer (score 2):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes a custom comparison function. I haven't tested this, but yours might look something like:

```
bool cmp (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)
{
    if ( lhs.y < rhs.y ) return true;
    else if ( lhs.y == rhs.y ) return ( lhs.x < rhs.x );
    else return false;
}
```